# Make cleveref work with figures in makenote marginalia

Tags: cross-referencing, captions, cleveref, scrlayer-notecolumn

I often want to include a small figure in the margin to illustrate a point in the main text.

To do this I am using scrlayer-notcolumn in with komascript.
In particular the `\makenote*` macro because that is robust, which is required e.g. if they images are being created using tikz.

I'm also using `captionof` from the caption package, to have captions outside of floats.

I am using cleveref to do my references to figures.

My images an there captions are showing up fine.
However, when I put in a `\Cref{fig:myfig}` for a label that is in a `makenote`, it never works, only displaying `??`.
Plain-old `\ref` works fine however

Example code:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage{scrlayer-notecolumn}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{cleveref}



\begin{document}

\section{start}

Do not forget  to consider the image in \Cref{fig:foo} or \Cref{fig:bar}.
Or more plainly Figure \ref{fig:foo} or Figure \ref{fig:bar}

\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
    \includegraphics{dummy}
    \captionof{figure}{Here is the inline figure caption}
    \label{fig:foo}
\end{minipage}

\makenote*{
    \includegraphics{dummy}
    \captionof{figure}{Here is the side figure caption}
    \label{fig:bar}
}
\end{document}
```

Output (after 2+ builds with pdflatex):
[image: the output note the ?? marks]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`scrlayer-notecolumn` restores in the `\label` after a `\makenote` command to the version it has found after loading the package, this is the `\label` - version before `cleveref` changed it -- this way, `cleveref` can't write cross-referencing information to the `.aux` file and does not store its own label version; Neither `\cref` nor `\Cref` can find anything useful to work with and display `??`.

A possible (perhaps the quickest) solution is to load `scrlayer-notecolumn` **after** `cleveref`, making it one of the rare packages that should be loaded last.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{scrlayer-notecolumn}




\begin{document}

\section{start}

Do not forget  to consider the image in \Cref{fig:foo} or \Cref{fig:bar}.
Or more plainly Figure \ref{fig:foo} or Figure \ref{fig:bar}

\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
    \includegraphics{dummy}
    \captionof{figure}{Here is the inline figure caption}
    \label{fig:foo}
\end{minipage}

\makenote*{
    \includegraphics{dummy}
    \captionof{figure}{Here is the side figure caption}
    \label{fig:bar}
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `hyperref` -- last, `cleveref` -- laster, `scrlayer-notecolumn` -- lastest

Comment: hmm, this is a problem. I am loading `scrlayer-notecolumn` inside my (custom) document class, but I am loading cleverref inside the document using `usepackage`.

Comment: @LyndonWhite: Try `\RequirePackage{etoolbox}` and then say `\AtEndPreamble{\RequirePackage{scrlayer-notecolumn}}` and put the code related to that also there. This way you should be able to load `cleveref` before `scrlayer-notecolumn`.

Comment: Awesome, I just used this in my document and it is all working now.
Not only that, but  I can also use `hyperref` again, which I see now was broken for the same reason